# Ruby On Rails sort the array of hash based on priority

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Please help me finding the solution sort by based on priority
Im not getting the solution**

priority based on:

- 1st pick earliest slot
- 2nd max rating
- 3rd cronofy_enabled

```
interview_proposal = [
  { interviewer_id: 3903, rating: 4, cronofy_enabled: false, slot_date: "2022-05-09" },
  { interviewer_id: 10, rating: 3.5, cronofy_enabled: false, slot_date: "2022-05-06" },
  { interviewer_id: 3902, rating: 2, cronofy_enabled: true, slot_date: "2022-05-06" },
{ interviewer_id: 3904, rating: 2.5, cronofy_enabled: false, slot_date: "2022-05-09" },
{ interviewer_id: 3905, rating: 3.5, cronofy_enabled: false, slot_date: "2022-05-09" }
]
    
# First priority picked earliest_slot
@earliest_slot = interview_proposal.find{|proposal| proposal[:slot_date] == "2022-05-06"}
#second priority rating
@max_rating = interview_proposal.max_by{|proposal| proposal[:rating]}
# Third priority cronofy_enabled
@calendar_synced = interview_proposal.find{|proposal| proposal[:cronofy_enabled]}
    
sorted_array = []
interview_proposal.each do |interview_proposal|
  priority = match_count
  sorted_array << { priority: priority, interview_proposal: interview_proposal }
end
sorted_array = sorted_array.
  sort_by { |obj| obj[:priority] }.
  reverse.map { |obj| obj[:interview_proposal] }
sorted_array
    
def match_count
  count = 0
  count += 1 if @earliest_slot[:slot_date].present?
  count += 1 if @max_rating[:rating].present?
  count += 1 if @calendar_synced[:cronofy_enabled]
  count
end
```

Comment: It appears you want `interview_proposal.sort_by { |h| [h[:slot_date], h[:rating], h[:cronofy_enabled] ? 1 : 0] }`. Note that [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) uses [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (see especially the doc's 3rd paragraph) to order elements. `sort_by` tends to be more efficient than [Array#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) because the 3-element arrrays it sorts are computed only once.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you can reduce the overhead in your code by using [Ruby's sort method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort). All you need to provide in each block iteration for the sort to work is a positive integer if a > b, 0 if they are equal and a negative integer if b >a. The starship operator <=> is a nice shortcut to use for the first two cases but does not work on booleans so we added the extra logic there.

```
sorted_array = interview_proposal.sort do |a, b|

   if  (a[:slot_date] <=> b[:slot_date]) != 0
      a[:slot_date] <=> b[:slot_date] 
   elsif (a[:rating] <=> b[:rating]) != 0
      a[:rating] <=> b[:rating]
   elsif a[:cronofy_enabled] == b[:cronofy_enabled]
       0
   elsif a[:cronofy_enabled]
       1
   else 
      -1
   end
end
```

---

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're right thanks for the correction

Comment: Alternatively, `else a[:cronofy_enabled] ? 1 : 0 <=> a[:cronofy_enabled] ? 1 : 0`.